# Duplicate values of an array within another array

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, countif

I have an array which is a subset of another array, I want to know if how many unique entries/duplicates (of the whole array) are there in that subset.

[image: !https://imgur.com/a/9UO2HrJ]

In the image, I'm looking for the formula to insert in the highlighted cells...
Meaning I need to know, for every date how many of the entries were unique and how many were duplicates

Comment: Welcome. Please adjust your image to show the expected outcome.

Answer (score 0):

paste in **E2** cell and drag down:

```
=COUNTIF(B:B, D2)
```

[image: 0]